# Eager load self - join table recursively

Tags: ruby, recursion, activerecord, eager-loading

I have got a model

```
class MyModel < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :parent, :class_name => 'MyModel'
  has_many :children, :class_name => 'MyModel', :foreign_key => 'parent_id'
end
```

And I want to grab all objects that have no parent and get them with all the children. In another words I want all parents and their children and children of their children and so on. So it has to be eager loaded recursively.
If I do

```
    @result = MyModel.includes(:children)
             .where('parent IS ?', nil)
```

I get only parents with the one level of children. But I dont get children of children. Is it possible to get all of them recursively? And is it possible to albo add counting the number of children for each parent?

Answer (score 1):

You could recursively preload a set amount of self-joins by passing in a nested hash

```rb
@result = MyModel.includes(
  children: {
    children: {
      children: {
        children: :children
      }
    }
  }
).where('parent IS ?', nil)
```

Or better yet generate this hash dynamically

*This is untested (basically pseudo code)*

```rb
scope :recursivly_include_children, -> (max_depth) {
  includes(generate_nested_children_hash(max_depth))
}

def self.generate_nested_children_hash(current_hash = {}, level = 0, remaining_levels)
  if remaining_levels > 0
    // add one level to the current_hash here

    generate_nested_children_hash(current_hash, level+1, remaining_levels-1)
  else
    current_hash
  end
end
```

Then in the controller to get a maximum of 10 levels of preloaded children:

```
@result = MyModel.recursivly_include_children(10).where('parent IS ?', nil)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend you use a nested set gem like [awesome_nested_set](https://github.com/collectiveidea/awesome_nested_set). That will give you a lot of functionality to help with handling sets to similar objects, and includes the facility to store children count.

Comment: Then look at the gem code and get ideas from that - that's the beauty of Open Source